# Is there any way to list a macro in core files using GDB

Tags: macros, gdb, coredump

like if in a core file, we have a function then we list the function like

```
list <function_name>
```

but while doing the same thing with a macro it's stating like

```
Function <macro_name> not defined.
```

can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

> list a macro in core files using GDB

Note that *neither* function names, *nor* macro names are contained in the `core` file. They are contained in the *executable*.

To allow GDB to show macros, you must compile your executable with appropriate level of debug info (`-g3` for [GCC](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html#Compilation) if using `DWARF` platform), then use [macro expand](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html) GDB command.

Note that recompiling executable may render the existing `core` unusable, unless you can rebuild it from *exact* same sources. In particular, if the original executable was compiled with optimization (e.g. with `-O2`), then you *must* use the exact same options (just add `-g3` to the compile lines).